# Reset Image Template Variable in ModX

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I have an image template variable that is working, as far as selecting an image and having it display properly on my page. However, I am unable to "clear" the value of the image TV once set for a page. I'm assuming I need to put something into the default value for the TV, then hit the small "set to default" green arrow on the templates TV page, but I've tried `""`, `" "`, and `"<!-- No Image -->"` to no success.

This must be an easy thing I'm overlooking.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean in the manager when editing a resource? Click in the image TV dropdown and hit backspace to clear out the value, then save.

Comment: Thanks! I just got an answer to this on the MODX forums at roughly the same time too. I had no idea that the drop downs were actually text-boxes as well.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
[[*imagetv:empty=`<img src="/assets/img/no_img.jpg">`]]
```

Comment: This won't solve the problem of having selected an image, then wanting to empty that tv. Also, I prefer that no html be put on the page if the tv is empty.